# Find Even and Odd columns and rows of Bitmap with LockBits() function

Tags: c#, bitmap, lockbits

im using the second block code to find  Even and Odd columns of a bitmap in order to build a Checkered page in bitmap i used my IsEven() and IsOdd() function

i want to do this job with lockbits:

```
public unsafe void DrawCheckeredPage()
    {
        Bitmap bmpShati = null;
        bmpShati = new Bitmap(@"\ColorReductedBMP.bmp");
        Color GrayOne = Color.FromArgb(153, 153, 153);
        Color WhiteOne = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);

        for (int x = 0; x < bmpShati.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bmpShati.Height; y++)
            {
                Color PreCol = bmpShati.GetPixel(x, y);
                if (OmitedPictureBoxes.Exists(item => (Color)item.Tag == PreCol))
                {
                    if (IsEven(x) && IsEven(y))
                    {
                        bmpShati.SetPixel(x, y, GrayOne);
                    }
                    else if (IsOdd(x) && IsOdd(y))
                    {
                        bmpShati.SetPixel(x, y, GrayOne);
                    }
                    else if (IsEven(x) && IsOdd(y))
                    {
                        bmpShati.SetPixel(x, y, WhiteOne);
                    }
                    else if (IsOdd(x) && IsEven(y))
                    {
                        bmpShati.SetPixel(x, y, WhiteOne);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        bmpShati = resizeBitmap2(bmpShati, newW, newH);
        pbMain.Invoke((Action)(() => pbMain.Image = bmpShati));
    }
```

but there is a problem that Checkered page is not drawing correct i did it with GetPixel() and SetPixel but i i must use LockBits, can you please help me?

**here is my code :**

```
public unsafe void DrawCheckeredPage()
        {
            Bitmap bmpShati = null;
            bmpShati = new Bitmap(@"\ColorReductedBMP.bmp");
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpShati.Width, bmpShati.Height);
            var _bdata = bmpShati.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
            var _ptr = (byte*)_bdata.Scan0;
            int _numBytes = _bdata.Stride * _bdata.Height, row, col;
            for (int i = 0; i < _numBytes; i += 4)
            {
                Color PreCol = Color.FromArgb(
                    (*(_ptr + i + 2)),
                    (*(_ptr + i + 1)),
                    (*(_ptr + i))
                    );
                if (OmitedPictureBoxes.Exists(item => (Color)item.Tag == PreCol))
                {
                    row = i / _bdata.Stride;
                    col = i % _bdata.Stride;
                    if (IsEven(row) && IsEven(col))
                    {

                        (*(_ptr + i + 2)) = Convert.ToByte(153);
                        (*(_ptr + i + 1)) = Convert.ToByte(153);
                        (*(_ptr + i)) = Convert.ToByte(153);

                    }
                    else if (IsOdd(row) && IsOdd(col))
                    {
                        (*(_ptr + i + 2)) = Convert.ToByte(153);
                        (*(_ptr + i + 1)) = Convert.ToByte(153);
                        (*(_ptr + i)) = Convert.ToByte(153);

                    }
                    else if (IsEven(row) && IsOdd(col))
                    {
                        (*(_ptr + i + 2)) = Convert.ToByte(255);
                        (*(_ptr + i + 1)) = Convert.ToByte(255);
                        (*(_ptr + i)) = Convert.ToByte(255);
                    }
                    else if (IsOdd(row) && IsEven(col))
                    {
                        (*(_ptr + i + 2)) = Convert.ToByte(255);
                        (*(_ptr + i + 1)) = Convert.ToByte(255);
                        (*(_ptr + i)) = Convert.ToByte(255);
                    }
                }
            }
            bmpShati.UnlockBits(_bdata);
            bmpShati = resizeBitmap2(bmpShati, newW, newH);
            pbMain.Invoke((Action)(() => pbMain.Image = bmpShati));
        }
        public bool IsOdd(int value)
    {
        return value % 2 != 0;
    }
    public static bool IsEven(int value)
    {
        return value % 2 == 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please describe what you want the code to do, what it is currently doing, and the difference between the two.

Comment: @mjwills i have added the code with set and get pixel i want to do that exact thing with lockbits()

Comment: Your bitmap is called "ColorReductedBMP.bmp". Is it actually 32bpp, then? You can't assume the `PixelFormat` given to `LockBits` without being certain about it.